# Add url parameter to css file in asp themes folder

Tags: asp.net, css, app-themes

I have written a bit of code that helps with versioning of js files. Essentially it spins around the current script manager and appends the javascript file path with an md5 hash of the file. So

```
<script src="../Javascript/Navigation.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
```

becomes

```
<script src="../Javascript/Navigation.js?md5=70D2B4D1F236C7E340D9152B9E4102C3" type="text/javascript"></script>
```

I think this is a fairly common thing to do (or variants of it). What I am struggling to do is pick up the css files in the app_themes folder and do the same.

How do I get in and change the css links?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

You can use a control adapter to neatly inject this behavior into the page as follows:

```
public class PageAdapter : System.Web.UI.Adapters.PageAdapter
{
    protected override void OnPreRender(System.EventArgs e)
    {
        foreach (var link in Page.Header.Controls.OfType<HtmlLink>().ToList())
            if (link.Attributes["type"].Equals("text/css", StringComparison.OrdinalIgnoreCase))
                if (link.Attributes["href"].Contains("/App_Themes/{0}/".Fill(Page.Theme), StringComparison.OrdinalIgnoreCase))
                   /* process link */

        base.OnPreRender(e);
    }
}
```

You can plug it in by saving the following as a ***.browser** file in the **App_Browsers** folder:

```
<browsers>
  <browser refID="Default">
    <controlAdapters>
      <adapter controlType="System.Web.UI.Page"
               adapterType="PageAdapter" />
    </controlAdapters>
  </browser>
</browsers>
```

Overall, I think **Control Adapters** are a powerful AOP-like mechanism for injecting behavior into control/page life-cycles; they are almost entirely ignored in favor of traditional sub-classing.

Answer (score 3):

I am facing one issue that it is repeating css entry in html markup on every postback.
for example, I have newabc.css. the code will change it to newabc.css?v=1. if I see html source after 5 postback, it will have 5 "newabc.css?v=1". so I added link.EnableViewState = False, it works fine but is it actually needed?

```
    Dim link As HtmlLink = Nothing

    For Each c As Control In Page.Header.Controls
        If TypeOf c Is HtmlLink Then
            link = TryCast(c, HtmlLink)

            If link.Href.IndexOf("App_Themes/", StringComparison.InvariantCultureIgnoreCase) >= 0 AndAlso link.Href.EndsWith(".css", StringComparison.InvariantCultureIgnoreCase) Then
                link.Href &= "?v=" & VER_CSS
                'link.EnableViewState = False
            End If
        End If
    Next
```

Comment: I had the same problem.
As a matter of fact, I have several css files in the App_Themes folder and after a postback the page refers to the first css file on all link tags in the head!
For example : I have a.css, b.css and c.css. The page ends up with 3 links to all refering to a.css!

Setting the EnableViewState to false seems to be the fix for this.

Answer (score 1):

Avoid to invent the wheel twice by using [Combres](http://combres.codeplex.com/) instead. Does everything you ask for, and more!